# How to access value attributes of dynamically created <select> tag dropdown, using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Here's the jsfiddle link to a small mockup of what I am trying to do http://jsfiddle.net/dscLc/8/

Javascipt code

```
newc=function(){
$('#div').html('<center><select id="resClass"><option value="" selected>FIRST</option></select><center>');
    for(var i=0;i<10;i+=1)
    {
        $('#resClass').append('<option value="'+i+'">'+i+'</option>');
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#resClass").change(function(){
        alert($(this).val());
    });
});
```

HTML code goes here

```
<div id="div">
    <center>
        <button type="button" onclick="newc()">Compare</button>
    </center>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you using an `onclick` attribute? You should not do that, you are already using jQuery to attach event handlers. You are just confusing yourself even more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Also this seems that you have a static parent with an id `#div` so you can delegate to this element. Although `$(document) && $(document.body)` are always available to event delegation, but this is very slow in terms of performance.

Better to delegate the event to the closest static parent, where dom lookup time is low and performance is fast.

change this:

```
$("#resClass").change(function(){
```

to this:

```
$("#div").on('change', "#resClass", function(){
```

---

This is a case of event delegation.

What this means if any element is dynamically generated then you can't bind an event to that element the way you are currently trying to bind, because when dom was ready this element was not available at that point of time.

Comment: +1 for suggesting the closest non-changing parent as the delegate target. As the operation is at user-interface speed though you are concerned about the efficiency where it does not matter! :)

Answer (score 2):

As you are adding the select dynamically, You need [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/):

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the future.

```
$("#div").on('change','#resClass',function(){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dscLc/14/)**

Comment: +1 for suggesting using the nearest "non changing" parent element for the event delegation. Speed-wise `document` would do, as it is a single mouse click, but this is a good habit to follow :)

Answer (score 1):

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Lcr5t/

API: `.on` - http://api.jquery.com/on/

Rest should fit the need `:)`

**Code**

```
newc=function()
{
    $('#div').html('<center><select id="resClass"><option value="" selected>FIRST</option></select><center>');
    for(var i=0;i<10;i+=1)
    {
        $('#resClass').append('<option value="'+i+'">'+i+'</option>');
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('change',"#resClass",function(){
        alert($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Comment: Why was this **FIRST** *working answer* down-voted? Don't be shy. Speak up :)

Comment: @MilindAnantwar heh I will never understand this `:)` siiigh

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie No Idea `:)` I bet someone dint liked a smily! `:P`

Comment: @Tats_innit: i can understand. this is very annoying. +1 for being first at place....

Comment: +1 to compensate: This was the first correct answer.

Comment: Wasn't me, but just tossing a wall of code to the newbie will not really help him.

Comment: @kapa: Its the users own code (aside from the small fix)!

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie But how will he understand WHY he should write it like that? If he was capable of reading the docs, ot AT LEAST the basic tutorials, he would already know the answer without asking. OK, you help him for now by just giving the code. But next time, he will be just as clueless, if you do not explain.

Comment: @Kapa `:)` huh explaination and attachment to `.on` documentation should be well explanatory isn't it?

Comment: @kapa: that doesnt mean he should be getting donwvote when the answer is perfect solution to question. how hard is it to put a comment to aking them to update the answer with relevant info rather than carelessly downvoting it....

Comment: @kapa: The purpose of a down-vote is "if the answer is not useful". That does not apply here (even if it could do with some more explanation)

Comment: @MilindAnantwar I understand people who do not comment, only downvote. I was not the downvoter, and I already have 3 people questioning me :). Nobody wants to get into useless arguments all the time. I commented, but the answer is still not any better. I don't think these answers (same code posted 5-10 times) are useful, even though they are working code.

Comment: @Kapa anyhoo, lets stop these comment and you can answer much improved version. Have fun yo! take it easy `:)`

Comment: I don't get it, I'm certainly not fighting :). I tried to help by explaining the downvote, because everybody seemed clueless. Please note that this is only my 4th comment here (and hopefully the last).

Comment: My downvote - was just a code block with no explanation as to why the fix would work or what the difference is (when I voted), which is only partially useful.  Thus the downvote, sorry.  New answer is better, but still doesn't explain why they should use 'on' rather than 'click'.

Comment: Compare with the accepted answer for a reasonable comparison as to what I am talking about.

Answer (score 1):

You event hookup needs to use 'on' to apply it to any controls that are subsequently created after it has been registered:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("change", "#resClass", function(){
        alert($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your must to use delegated events like as `.on, .bind, .live`

Answer (score -1):

There is a small problem in your code.

First, you have not called the function `newc()`.
Secondly, since the `select` element is dynamically added, `change()` is not triggered.

Please check the following code:

```
newc=function(){
    $('#div').html('<center><select id="resClass"><option value="" selected>FIRST</option></select><center>');
    for(var i=0;i<10;i+=1)  {
        $('#resClass').append('<option value="'+i+'">'+i+'</option>');
    }
}
newc();
$(document).on('change','#resClass',function(){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ardeezstyle/dscLc/18/)

Comment: `newc` was called in `onlick` of button :) You should also explain *why* you use event delegation with `on`.

Comment: Oops I did not see the html. :)

Comment: Made the same mistake myself at first :)